# jQuery error Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I almost got everything working in this step in my code, however, the code works but for some reason still shows a console issue that I can't seem to fix.

index.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header text-white">
                    To-Do List
                    <a href="#collapseToDo" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-auto"></i></a>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseToDo">
                            <form class="" action="/" method="POST">
                                <input class="list-group-item bg-light rounded-0" name="todo" type="text" placeholder="Enter To-Do"/>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                    <% todos.forEach(function(todos){ %>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><%= todos.title %> <form action="/<%= todos._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST"><button><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></form></li>
                    <% }) %>
                </ul>
            </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

dom.js

```
$("ul").on("click", "button", function(event){
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which === 13){
          var todoText = $(this).val(); 
          $(this).form.submit();
          $(".list-group").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + todoText + "<span><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></span></li>");
          $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $(".list-group").on("click", "li", function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass("completed");
    });
```

I can't seem to get `$(this).form.submit()` to work without any errors. I get the following error: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

The weird thing is. The form does end up being succesfully submitted, however the next line in the eventlistener doesn't go through because of the error. Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line:

```
$(this).form.submit();
```

`this` refers to the `input` where the `keypress` happened. `input` elements don't have a `form` property, so that is `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have a `submit` method, hence your `Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined` error.

Now, the reason that the form does wind up submitting (or at least starts to) is because you don't have a `submit` button in your `form` and pressing ENTER (character code 13) causes a `submit` in that case.

Change the line to:

```
$(this).closest("form").submit();
```

so that the nearest `form` ancestor element of the `input` will be found and then `submit` will be called on that. Or, remove the line entirely and let the pressing of the ENTER key start the submit process as it natively does anyway.

FYI: The `keypress` event has been deprecated. Use `keydown` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Everything you said makes a lot of sense, however I end up with a weird issue where the entire value of the input is not submitted with the form now. I end up with an empty string added to my database instead.

Comment: @YaadMohammad Well, I think that is just a matter of your decision to submit the form at this event. If you submit the form during a key event, it doesn't give the user a chance to complete their data entry before the form gets submitted. If you use `keydown`, the event triggers before the character has been added to the control. (I know I said to use it instead of `keypress`, but I wasn't thinking big picture in terms of your code). To solve this issue, use the `change` event of the `input` element because it only fires when the control loses focus and the value has changed.